# Protocol and data format to get connected with HSM boards

Tags: security, encryption, protocols, hsm, hardware-security-module

Folks - How does an application connect with HSM(Hardware security Module) boards? What is the protocol they use and what would be the data formats for interaction? The reason for asking protocol is that I may have the application running on a physical machine connected directly to the network where HSM is installed or I can have the application deployed on the cloud too. So, how do I connect?

For example, if I have a Java application and want to connect with a HSM, say Luna SA, what is the protocol that I use to connect with the HSM board?

FYI, I have seen some related questions already, as listed. But, nowhere I could understand the actual communication protocol and data formats.

[Connect SafeNet HSM using Java remotely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28233822/connect-safenet-hsm-using-java-remotely)

[How do I integrate HSM encryption with JAVA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12981977/how-do-i-integrate-hsm-encryption-with-java)

Comment: Did you find what is the protocol being used to interact with HSM? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It is HSM-vendor specific.  There will be host libraries that convert standard-based APIs (PKCS#11, CNG, JCE, etc) into the proprietary comms protocol, and then it is sent to the HSM.  On receipt of a response, the response is format shifted back into whatever the API expects, which is then passed back to your code.

Unless you are writing code that will run on the HSM, you don't need to worry about how the vendor's libraries do their magic.